# Read each line of a HTML file using power shell and export the text between two HTML tags

Tags: html, powershell

I have an HTML file and I want to export the contents between two HTML tags in each line till EOF using powershell.

Example:

```
<tr valign="top">
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #efcb05; "><code><span class="sf17b16"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;"software_name": "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2979575v2)",</span>&nbsp;</code></td>
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #c0c0c0; "><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #efcb05; "><code><span class="sf17b16"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;"software_version": 2,</span>&nbsp;</code></td>
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #c0c0c0; "><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
</tr>
```

I want the output as

```
"software_name": "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2979575v2)"
"software_version": 2"
```

Comment: Which HTML tags? What did you tried so far?

Comment: Between, <span class="sf17b16"> *** </span>, ignoring the "&nbsp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple regex to capture the desired content and replace all `&nbsp;` using the `-replace`function and use `Trim()`to remove empty spaces and commas

```
$result = [regex]::Matches($content, 'class="sf17b16".*?>(.*?)</span>')
$result | select { ($_.Groups[1].Value -replace '&nbsp;', '').Trim().Trim(',') }
```

Output:

```
"software_name": "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2979575v2)"                                                                                     
"software_version": 2
```

**Note**: `$content`is the content of the html - if you parse a file, it would look like `$content = Get-Content c:\yourfile.html`

Comment: In addition to this, whenever the regex matches, it should check the immediate next line. And if the immediate next line is "</tr>" then it should print " Sample1" else print "Sample2". And then it should continue to print the result. Then goes for the next regex match and so on.. I'm completely new to PS, so tolerate :-)

Comment: since this questions is answerd, you should accept the answer (using the green checkmark) and ask a new question.

Comment: Well, its Checked now! Should the new question be posted in a new thread?

Comment: Yes, you should create a new thread, include sample data and the output you want to get. **AND** provide code what you've tried so far since stackoverflow is not a place to obtain full coding solutions rather its a place to help fix the code you've written http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve