# Power shell: Export strings between two HTML tags in different colours based on immediate next line

Tags: html, powershell

I have a big HTML file, following is a sample):

```html
<tr valign="top">
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #efcb05; "><code><span class="sf17b16"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;"software_name": "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2979575v2)",</span>&nbsp;</code></td>
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #c0c0c0; "><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #c0c0c0; "><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #efcb05; "><code><span class="sf17b16"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;"system_id": 3,</span>&nbsp;</code></td>
</tr>
```

I have to export the text between `<span class="sf17b16">`and `</span>`, ignoring the "&nbsp". If the immediate next line of the above said pattern starts with `</tr>` then the text colour of that string should be different from the others.

Expected output:

"software_name": "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2979575v2)"
"system_id": 3 (Different colour)

Also I have to export all the results to a HTML file.

Following is what I tried (Crappy), but it din't work.

```psh
$file = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.htm"
$content= gc "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.htm"
$pattern = 'sf17b16'
$line = Select-String $pattern $file | ForEach-Object {$_.LineNumber}
if ($line -match '^</tr>')
{
{
$result = [regex]::Matches($content, 'class="sf17b16".*?>(.*?)</span>')
$result | select {($_.Groups[1].Value -replace '&nbsp;', '').Trim().Trim(',')}
}
else
{
$result = [regex]::Matches($content, 'class="sf17b16".*?>(.*?)</span>')
$result | select {($_.Groups[1].Value -replace '&nbsp;', '').Trim().Trim(',')}
}
} | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output.html
```

Note: Related to thread, [Read each line of a HTML file using power shell and export the text between two HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941962/read-each-line-of-a-html-file-using-power-shell-and-export-the-text-between-two)

Comment: What is your PowerShell version. Newer ones can parse this properly without the use of regex.

Comment: I have version 2.0, I would like to do it in this way, since there are few other scripts depend on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a RegEx solution? Ok, we can do RegEx. This will output an array of objects with 2 properties. One is the value of the search, and the other is if the next row is . How you format or output is up to you, but it gets you the data you want to work with...

```
$Source = @"
<tr valign="top">
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #efcb05; "><code><span class="sf17b16"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;"software_name": "Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (KB2979575v2)",</span>&nbsp;</code></td>
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #c0c0c0; "><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
</tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #c0c0c0; "><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
<td class="ln"></td><td style="color: #000000; background-color: #efcb05; "><code><span class="sf17b16"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;"system_id": 3,</span>&nbsp;</code></td>
</tr>
"@
$Data = ([regex]"class=`"sf17b16`".*?>(?: &nbsp;)*(.*?),<\/span>.*?`r`n(?:<td|<\/tr>)").matches($source)|%{[PSCustomObject]@{'Value' = $_.groups[1].value;'NextRowIsTR'=$_.value -match '<\/tr>$'}}
$Data
```

You want to run that against a file? Just change the source... just make sure it's all one string to search against for your RegEx matching by joining the array of strings into one multi-line string.

```
$Source = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.htm" -join "`r`n"
```